# If true … else Shorthand

Tags: javascript, if-statement, shorthand

I know that the normal use case for this if statement is e.g.

```
var string = boolean ? "this" : "that";
```

I use jhint in my editor and when i try something like

```
boolean ? array.push("this") : array.slice("that",1);
```

jshint throws (W030) "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"

So far the code always worked fine but maybe i was just lucky.

So my question is, why should i not use this pattern and what would be an alternative? Because writing

```
if(boolean){
    array.push("this");
} else {
    array.splice("that",1);
}
```

for such short instructions really give me the creeps.

thank you.

Comment: JSLint complains about it for readability reasons. Which of the two you think is more readable? Code is read a lot more than it is written. It should not 'give you the creeps' to write one more line.

Comment: Add `/*jshint -W030 */` to the top of the file to remove the warning, or updated your `.jshint` file.

Comment: `array.push` modifies the array but `array.slice` does not. The portion after `:` has no effect, is there a raeson you used it?

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to wrap the ternary operator inside the [**`void operator`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) like this:

```
void(cond ? expr1 : expr2);
```

This achieves the desired result and passes JSHint. See [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ewkrv1j2/) and click JSHint button.

However, I recommend the following syntax:

```
if (cond) {
    expr1;
} else {
    expr2;
}
```

Because it is more readable. Just because JavaScript lets you do strange things does not mean that you should.

Answer (score 3):

What it complains about is you misappropriating the [conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). It is an operator not a control structure. So it lives in the category of such things things as `+,-,*,/`. That means you expect the first operand to be a boolean and the second and third to yield a return value.

The whole thing is meant to be short for

```
  if (boolean) {
   string ="this" ;
  } else {
   string ="that";
  }
```

It wants to return a value (which it can't in your case) and it expects you to use that value (which you don't). So the tenary if is not the thing to use for your case and as a result makes it far less readable.

Answer (score 1):

You are using side effects in expressions to execute logic.

Indeed not very friendly code. It will work.

Just rewrite to distinct logic from expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can circumvent the jshint message using:

```
void(boolean ? array.push("this") : array.slice("that",1));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use the ternary operater for this kind of operation in a clean way, then you can do it like this:

```
array[cond ? 'push' : 'slice'](cond ? "this" : "that", cond ? 1 : undefined);
```

or

```
array[cond ? 'push' : 'slice'].apply(null, cond ? ["this"] : ["that", 1]);
```

But anyway you may prefer a boring if statement.